# Sending fixed sized udp packets with raw data with gstreamer to inteface with gnuradio

Tags: audio, udp, gstreamer, gnuradio

I'm trying to interface gstreamer with gnuradio. Gnuradio has input block which receives data in fixed payload size udp packets https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/sphinx-3.7.0/blocks/networking_tools_blk.html. There is no protocol implied: each udp packet should contain the same amount of signed shorts (16bit le).

Apparently gstreamer can send udp packets with `udpsink`. I tried running

```
gst-launch-1.0  audiotestsrc wave=saw ! queue2 ! audioconvert  ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

I hooked up wireshark and find out that the packet size is 2048 bytes. I provided this to GNUradio and everything worked fine.

However, when I tried mp3 source file in gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/adamov/Kerensky_Interview_1964.mp3  ! mpegaudioparse ! mpg123audiodec ! queue ! audioconvert  ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

the results were completely garbled. I discovered with wireshark that packet size vary between 5016 and 5012 bytes.

Any idea how to force fixed packet size in gstreamer? Any alternative way to send raw data to udp?

PS: Here is the gnuradio flow graph for testing
[image: Flow graph]

Comment: NEVER use a throttle together with a hardware sink. In fact, your GRC complains about that (unless you're using a very old version of GNU Radio, before I added that warning).

Comment: Well, the presence of throttle doesn't change anything, apparently.

Comment: no, not w.r.t. your problem, but it introduces a two-clock problem, where the sound card and the operating system's "sleep" function compete for controlling a rate. That will lead to problems.

Comment: So far, the best results are achieved by using fifo file for communicating like described here: http://wiki.opendigitalradio.org/Simple_FM_transmitter_using_gnuradio and using `filesink location=file.fifo` in gstreamer. But gstreamer closes fifo unexpectedly sometimes and this causes gnuradio to quit on sigpipe.

Comment: Try exploring the `udpsink` properties `bytes-to-serve` and `buffer-size`, not sure if it might help.